# storing row into another table in json format using stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have one table named product

```
product_id    quantity     model 
   1             4          vt-32
   4             2          mt-21
```

product-modified table

```
  product_id        product_modified
```

what i want is when any update will happen in product table , i want to set up one stored procedure in mysql that will update product_modified table like this

Suppose i update product table

```
product_id    quantity     model 
   1             4          vt-31
   4             2          mt-21
```

then my product_modified table will look like this

```
  product-modified table

  product_id        product_modified
     1              { old : {product_id:1,quantity:4}
                      new : {model:vt-31} }
```

this is what i want and please this is one sample example there can be many columns in table so just see this example as a sample case and can we do this using stored procedure mysql

Comment: You can do this with an [`on update` trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html). You can then compare each `new.column` and `old.column`-values and use `concat` to create your result string and then insert it to your log table. Try it, post your code, and we can correct it if you get problems.

Comment: but the problem with trigger is that we have to compare each column what if there are 100 columns in table

Comment: A trigger can do most of the things that are possible in a stored procedure, but a) it executes "when any update will happen in product table" and b) can access both "old" and "new" values (well, in case of an update). And yes, you have to compare all 100 columns in the table (at least if you want to do it efficiently), that is how a database works, the columns are not like an array. But that would be true for a stored procedure too (that wouldn't know about the changed values). And it's just copy&paste: write it for one column, then replace the column name (e.g. with an excel formula).

Comment: using trigger for doing this instead of stored procedure

Comment: Ah, and btw: json is not something a database particularly "likes" (because it is hard to reuse this data inside the database). Usual ways to save a (change) history are to have a history table with all the columns of the original table (plus id and timestamp), either all or just the changed values, or a table that contains `(id, tablename, columnname, oldvalue, newvalue, timestamp)`. But if you need the json for e.g. your application, you can save it that way.

Comment: please solve my problem i have posted today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609326/1064-check-the-manual-that-corresponds-to-your-mysql-server-version-for-the-rig?noredirect=1#comment70420602_41609326